# Ajax response contains the source code of the page and not the final content of the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to receive, using ajax, a value from a page. The value is printed only when a specific javascript code is executed.

page1.html:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "GET",
   url: "./page2.html",
   dataType: "text",
   success : function(data){
      alert ( $(data).filter("#returnvalue").html() );
   }
})
```

page2.html

```
<div id='returnvalue'>AAA</div>
<script>
  var cond = true;
  if(cond){
    document.getElementById("returnvalue").innerHTML = "BBB";
  }
</script>
```

My alert prints "AAA". why?

It's like the javascript in the second page is not executed and i'm only receiving the source of the page and not the content of the page after changes.

What am i doing wrong? Does anyone have ideas/solutions?

Thank you very much.

Comment: The JavaScript in the AJAX page won't be executed no matter what. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/ for a workaround.

Comment: @Blazemonger thanks. is there a way to receive a response that executed the javascript?

Comment: page2.html or page2.php which page u r actually trying.

Comment: @BinsonEldhose He already edited the question to fix that.

Comment: @BinsonEldhose the same page, that was just a mistake.....

Comment: @MaRco If you put the entire `data` in `.html()`, the script will be executed.

Comment: More often than not it's a bad idea to do that anyway. Keep your javascripts in separate files and you'll be better organized.

Comment: ajax request will not excute the java script code in a html . you may use php scrip to change the doom

Comment: Highly probable that the Javascript on page2 is not executed by the time the output AAA is sent to your original page. Nor will it be executed since you are not interpreting the script but just getting it's output which is AAA. It's not getting interpreted by a browser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this should do what you want:

```
success : function(data){
    $("#somediv").html(data); // load the data into the DOM and execute scripts
    alert ( $("#returnvalue").html() );
}
```

Comment: Should be the right answer. As long as the script-tag is not loaded in the DOM it will not be executed. So you have to insert it into the DOM and wait for the execution.

Comment: Great solution. Thank you!! I just tried to implement it and seems to work. I am just wondering if the code is executed two times or just once.

Comment: Just once. Why would it be executed twice?

Comment: The only thing that executes it is `.html(data)`.

Comment: Basically in that script i'm starting a connection (XMPP server), and even if i wasn't checking the result the connection was made. The idea of using this ajax it was only to have a confirm that the connection had been made successfully

Comment: That seems to be the answer to a different question, like why don't you want it to be executed twice? I asked what made you think it _might_ be executed twice? You already discovered that `$.ajax` doesn't execute it, so what would cause a second exection?

Comment: I'm really confused about it. I guess the script was executing but the source of the page could not be changed... i don't know to be honest :)

Answer (score 0):

Write a function in page2 which will contain script(on document ready function).
I think, You are not making right use of Ajax response

```
success : function(data)
{
  $("#returnvalue").html(data);
}
```